# Ensuring 1 to 1 mapping through a many to many table

Tags: database-design

I've currently got a database with two tables, "Product" and "Option". Each parameter is tied to one product. We want to extend this data with a new concept of a "Project". A product will have many projects and each project will list what the default values for each option are for that product. The trouble I'm having is thinking how to ensure that each project lists every option for the product it's tied to.

E.g. if a product has options A, B, and C. Each project needs to define the default value for A, B, and C. Adding a new option should require updating all the projects.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: you need somewhere a *link table* that stores a reference to both every product (or project) and its options' values. Let's call that one `ProjectOptions`, and let's assume it's structured like `(ProjectId, OptionId, ValueForOption)`.

> The trouble I'm having is thinking how to ensure that each project lists every option for the product it's tied to.

You can have an `ON INSERT TRIGGER` on table `project` that, whenever you insert a new project, creates all the corresponding entries into the `ProjectOptions` table.

> Adding a new option should require updating all the projects.

Actually you need to *add* entries to your `ProjectOption` table, not just *update* the `Project` table itself.

You can have another `ON INSERT TRIGGER` on table `Options`. Whenever a new `Option` is inserted, for a certain ProductId, look for all projects having that ProductID, and add the corresponding `(ProductId, OptionID, DefaultValueForOptionID /* or NULL */)` entries into your `ProjectOption` table.

---

Apart from doing this via triggers, you may consider doing the same at the *application* layer. If the user inputting the new options needs to perform something (like setting specific values for existing projects), this cannot be handled at the *database* layer.

Answer (score 0):

Triggers or a job that runs every 5 minutes could handle making sure that all options for a product are represented for each project.

However, forcing an update is a matter for an application, as is forcing someone to set the default values  in the first place. If you create a record for the default but leave the value NULL (assuming that's not a valid option). you can use that in the app to signal that values need to have a default set.

---

*<sub>[Community wiki answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki) originally based on a question comment by [RDFozz](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/116653/rdfozz). Please edit it to improve it if you can.</sub>*